# segmentedcontrol in navigationbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to put this in a navigationbar, but doesnt show up, can u
have a look at it?

```
UISegmentedControl *seg1 = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]
initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"von mir", @"alle", nil]];
[seg1 setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
UIBarButtonItem *barItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:seg1];
UIBarButtonItem *flexItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
target:self action:nil];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setItems:[NSArray
arrayWithObjects:flexItem, barItem, flexItem, nil]];
[flexItem release];
[barItem release];
[seg1 release];
```

Comment: just a thought, cant you use IB to do this.

Comment: yes, but I am making interface with code for some reason

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UINavigationBar`'s `items` property only accepts an array of `UINavigationItem` objects, not `UIBarButtonItem` objects. You can't configure a navigation bar the same way as you do a `UIToolbar`. Instead, in your view controller, do this:

```
UISegmentedControl * seg1 = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]
    initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"von mir", @"alle", nil]];
[seg1 setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
self.navigationItem.titleView = seg1;
```

This adds the segmented control to the title view of your view controller's navigation item, which is a custom view that appears centered on the navigation bar.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting titleView does not work if you are using a Back button in your navigation controller. The documentation says titleView  "…is ignored if leftBarButtonItem is not nil". Is there another way to get a segmented control in that nav bar, just *exactly* as Apple shows in the UINavigationController class reference?  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Art/NavigationViews.jpg